# Загрузка файла через Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot

У меня есть dev серевер на котором крутится angular 2 по адрусу localhost:4200, и tomcat со Spring на localhost:8080.
Пробую загрузить файл на сервер следующим способом:
Код angular:

```
uploadAvatar(file:File){
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open("POST",`http://localhost:8080/api/upload/avatar`)
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data")
    xhr.send(file)
}
```

Код контроллера Spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/upload/avatar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file){
    log.info(file);
    return file.getName();
}
```

Но после попытки загрузить файл в java-консоли появляется ошибка:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; 
nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

Как исправить данную ошибку?
Спасибо.

Comment: Добавьте `@RequestBody` = `uploadFile(@RequestBody MultipartFile file)`

Comment: @BogdanK Такая же ошибка.

Comment: значит файл пустой, что-то не так отправляете, попробуйте через постер - если будет работать тогда проблема на стороне отправки

Comment: в контроллере все правильно (если учитывать `@RequestBody`)

Comment: или  попробуйте передать как параметр а контроллер измените на `uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile)`

Comment: @BogdanK Файл не пустой, пытаюсь загрузить аватарку.

Comment: @BogdanK насколько я понимаю `@RequestParam("file")` это если морда делается на jsp и как этот параметр из angular 2 передать не знаю, мб FormData позволяет эти параметры передавать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53949/discussion-between-bogdank-and-bleser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел решение моей проблемы, ниже я посторабсь подробно описать что я для этого сделал.

В качестве представления я использую Angular 2, отправка файла происходит следующим способом.

```
uploadFile(file:File){
    let form = new FormData();
    form.append("file",file)

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open("POST",`${URL}/api/upload/avatar`)
    xhr.send(form)
}
```

`Content-Type` и `boundary` в этом случаее прописываются автоматически.

На строне сервера нужно проделать следующие манипуляции:

Добавить два бина:

```
@Bean(name = "commonsMultipartResolver")
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}


@Bean
public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();

    factory.setMaxFileSize("10MB");
    factory.setMaxRequestSize("10MB");

    return factory.createMultipartConfig();
}
```

Контроллер выглядит так:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/upload/avatar", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public String uploadFile(@RequestPart MultipartFile file){
    log.info(file);
    return file.getOriginalFilename();
}
```